# Display Selection sorting and Quick Sorting

Tags: java, sorting

I want to check if my algorithms are correct for my quick sort method and my selection sort method. I believe that I have my Quick Sorting correct and my selection sorting correct as well but may need correcting. How can I display my sorting back?

Selection sorting

```
public class SelectionSort {

// complexity of O(n2)
public void selectionSort(int numbers[], int array_size) {

    int i;
    int j;
    int min;

    for (i = 0; i < array_size - 1; i++) {

        min = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < array_size; j++) {

            if (numbers[j] < numbers[min])
                min = j;

        }

        swap(numbers[i], numbers[min]);
    }
}

public void swap(int num1, int num2) {
    int temp;
    temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
}

}
```

Quick Sorting

```
public class QuickSort {

// complexity of O(n log n).
public void quickSort(int numbers[], int array_size) {

    quickSort(numbers, 0, array_size - 1);

}

public void quickSort(int numbers[], int left, int right) {

    int pivot;
    int leftHold;
    int rightHold;

    leftHold = left;
    rightHold = right;
    pivot = numbers[left];

    while (left < right) {

        while ((numbers[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
            right--;

        if (left != right) {
            numbers[left] = numbers[right];
            left++;
        }

        while ((numbers[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
            left++;

        if (left != right) {
            numbers[right] = numbers[left];
            right--;

        }
    }

    numbers[left] = pivot;
    pivot = left;
    left = leftHold;
    right = rightHold;

    if (left < pivot)

        quickSort(numbers, left, pivot - 1);

    if (right > pivot)

        quickSort(numbers, pivot + 1, right);

}
}
```

Main Class

```
public class sortTesting {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    QuickSort qsort = new QuickSort();
    SelectionSort ssort = new SelectionSort();

    int i;
    int numbers[] = { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };

    System.out.print("Values in the sort:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    qsort.quickSort(numbers, 1);
    ssort.selectionSort(numbers, 1);

    //display sort of quickSort
    //display sort of selectionSort

}

}
```

Comment: Print the array again after the sort?  You may also want to create two arrays, one for each sort...

Comment: Also, your `swap()` method will not affect the array at all. So your result wont be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Quicksort is completely fine,but there is a problem with your swap function in your selection sort.The problem is:

**In java primitives are passed by value**.

So, if you pass your 2 integers to swap function the swap will not be reflected in the calling function. It can be corrected by rather passing the array and the indices for which you want a swap . So the correct swap function is:

```
public void swap(int []numbers,int i,int min) {
    int temp;
    temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[min];
    numbers[min]=temp;
}
```

and the correct call is:

```
swap(numbers,i,min);
```

Now coming to your main function there is a type error by you, you have mentioned the array lengths as 1, which clearly is wrong, it is alwasy advisable that when mentioning array lengths in java use this

**array_identifier.length**

Also to provide the same unsorted array to other sorting algorithm, Use the method **clone()** to clone the unsorted array into another array and then send it to selection sort and therefore the correct Main class is:

```
public class sortTesting {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    QuickSort qsort = new QuickSort();
    SelectionSort ssort = new SelectionSort();

    int i;
    int numbers[] = { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };

    System.out.print("Values in the sort:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + "  ");
        System.out.println();
    }     
    int []numbers2=numbers.clone();
    qsort.quickSort(numbers, numbers.length);/*MENTION THE CORRECT ARRAY LENGTH*/        
    System.out.println("\nThe array after sorting using quick sort is");
    for(int e:numbers)
     System.out.print(e+"  ");    
    ssort.selectionSort(numbers2, numbers2.length);/*MENTION THE CORRECT ARRAY LENGTH*/    
    System.out.println("\nThe array after sorting using selection sort is");
    for(int e:numbers2)
     System.out.print(e+"  ");         
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing your arrays, why don't you write a function that checks their data are properly sorted?

```
public static boolean isSorted( int[] numbers ) {
    boolean result = true;
    int previous = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for ( int n : numbers ) {
        result &= (n > previous );
        previous = n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's easier to check a boolean than reading an array if it starts to get big.

Note: you might want to replace the > check by >=, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which return true or false based on whether you array is sorted or not.

```
public static final boolean isSorted(final int[] data) {
    for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i-1] > data[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**and use Arrays.toString(data) to print you sorted integer array**

Answer (score 0):

I am using simple sorting hope this code will help you.
Use this code:

```
cout<<"values before sorting"<<endl; 
for(i=0;i<=4;i++) 
{ 
    cout<<array[i]<<" "; 
} 
cout<<endl; 
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j <= 4; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[min])
        {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    if (min != i)
    {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[min];
        array[min] = temp;
    }
}
cout << "values after sorting" << endl;
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << " ";
}
```

}